# Progress bar for copying files

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to create a progress bar for a file copy in Qt.  [This](http://www.qtforum.org/article/24548/how-to-display-the-copy-progress-of-qfile-on-qprogressbar.html) is as close as I could find, however I believe this doesn't work because according to the Qt class documentation:

> Unlike other QIODevice implementations, such as QTcpSocket, QFile does
>   not emit the aboutToClose(), bytesWritten(), or readyRead() signals.
>   This implementation detail means that QFile is not suitable for
>   reading and writing certain types of files, such as device files on
>   Unix platforms.

How can I do something like this?  I don't know how to implement my own signals.

Here is my code:

```
void Replicator::anotbaandbFile(QDir source, QDir target)
{
    source.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    target.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoSymLinks);

    qDebug() << "Scanning: " << source.path();

    QStringList sourceFileList = source.entryList();
    QStringList targetFileList = target.entryList();
    for (int aCount = 0; aCount < sourceFileList.count(); aCount++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int bCount = 0; bCount < targetFileList.count(); bCount++)
            if (sourceFileList.at(aCount) == targetFileList.at(bCount))
                found = true;
        if (found == false)
        {

            sourceFile = new QFile(source.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            targetFile = new QFile(target.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            progressBar->setMinimum(0);
            progressBar->setMaximum(sourceFile->size());
            written = 0;
            connect(sourceFile,SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)),SLOT(onWrite(qint64)));
            sourceFile->copy(targetFile->fileName());
            //QFile::copy(source.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount), target.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            qDebug() << source.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount) << " " << target.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void Replicator::onWrite(qint64 w)
{
    written += w;
    progressBar->setValue( written );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

new code modified from above

```
if (found == false)
        {
            sourceFile = new QFile(source.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            targetFile = new QFile(target.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            progressBar->setMinimum(0);
            progressBar->setMaximum(sourceFile->size());
            QByteArray buffer;
            for (int count = 0; !(buffer = sourceFile->read(1000000)).isEmpty(); count+=1000000)
            {
                targetFile->write(buffer);
                progressBar->setValue(count);
            }
            //targetFile->write(buffer);
            //QFile::copy(source.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount), target.absolutePath()+"/"+sourceFileList.at(aCount));
            qDebug() << "copying " << sourceFile->fileName() << " to " << targetFile->fileName();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy large files by portions of fixed size, than count portions already copied and callculate of percentage of work by dividing it to overal count of portions.

```
int iWorkPercentage = (int)(((float)iPortionsProcessed / (float)iOveralPortions) * 100);
```

Comment: Thanks Mykola, I think I figured it out with your help.  I'll post the code in another following post.